# Association Mapping Not Working Doctrine using Symfony

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony

[Note] Im just learning doctrine and symfony 3.

Ask: What would be the relation for my doctrine if:

I have `Company` entity and I want to associate it to `Sub_agent` entity.

The user will perform add/edit/delete from my `Company` entity the same goes for my `Sub_agent` entity. In my `Sub_agent` form there's a dropdown for `Company` where user have to select to associate the sub_agent to company.

**`Company` Entity**

```
 -------------
| id  | name  |
--------------
| 1   | ABCD  |
| 2   | EFGH  |
 -------------
```

**`Sub-Agent` Entity**

```
 ------------------------------------
| id  | sub_agent_name | company_id  |
-------------------------------------
| 1   | ABAKADA        |   1         | 
| 2   | EGAHA          |   2         |
 ------------------------------------
```

User records: Sub-agent table

```
----------------------
id |  Name   | Company|
-----------------------
1  | ABAKADA | ABCD   |
2  | EGAHA   | EFGH   |
----------------------
```

What I did is,

**UPDATE MY CODE**

**Sub-agent Entity**

```
namespace SwipeBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;


/**
 * Sub_agent
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="sub_agent")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="SwipeBundle\Repository\Sub_agentRepository")
 */
class Sub_agent
{

    /**
     * Many Sub-agents have One Company.
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Company", inversedBy="sub_agent")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="company_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $companyId;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;



    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return Sub_agent
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set companyId
     *
     * @param string $companyId
     *
     * @return Sub_agent
     */
    public function setCompanyId($companyId)
    {
        $this->companyId = $companyId;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get companyId
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCompanyId()
    {
        return $this->companyId;
    }

}
```

**Company Entity**

```
namespace SwipeBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Company
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="company")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="SwipeBundle\Repository\CompanyRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */

class Company
{

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Sub_agent", mappedBy="companyId")
     */
    protected $sub_agent;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=100)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return Company
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the mapping like so:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
```

And then change your $company annotation like so:

```
/**
 * One Sub-agent has One Company.
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Company", inversedBy="sub_agent")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="company_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $company;
```

Try that, I think it should work.

**EDIT #2 - based on comments.**

add the same use statement to you Company Entity and also **add** this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Sub_agent", mappedBy="company")
 */
protected $sub_agent;
```

Seem the Doctrine documentation is not correct. I tried the same as you before and got errors as well.

EDIT #3:

You'll need to add:

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
```

To Company Entity, and also a contructor:

```
public function __construct() {
  $this->sub_agent = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

Change `$companyId` back to `$company`. You misunderstood me.
 You need setters and getters for getting setting Sub_agents to Company like so:

```
/**
* Set sub_agent
*
* @param \SwipeBundle\Entity\Sub_agent $subAgent
*
* @return Application
*/
public function setSubAgent(\SwipeBundle\Entity\Sub_agent $subAgent = null)
{
  $this->sub_agent = $subAgent;

  return $this;
}

/**
* Get sub_agent
*
* @return \SwipeBundle\Entity\Sub_agent
*/
public function getSubAgent()
{
  return $this->sub_agent;
}
```

Comment: Still not working, I update my code above and put your code, I update also the error I encounter.

Comment: I update my code again, same error:  `[Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\DriverException]                                                                                                           
  An exception occurred while executing 'ALTER TABLE sub_agent ADD CONSTRAINT FK_CACFF824979B1AD6 FOREIGN KEY (company_id) REFERENCES company (id)':  
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint `

Comment: Hi Same error; I update also my code just like you said. thank you, `[Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\DriverException]                                                                                                           
  An exception occurred while executing 'ALTER TABLE sub_agent ADD CONSTRAINT FK_CACFF824979B1AD6 FOREIGN KEY (company_id) REFERENCES company (id)':  
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint`

Comment: Everything looks exactly the same as what I have. Strange... Can you try clearing the cache using `php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod` and also `php bin/console cache:clear` and then run `php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force` again? The only other thing I'm thinking is maybe explicitly name your ids, for example `company_id` instead of `id` - but I'm thinking Doctrine should be able to detect that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133692/discussion-between-jlacsonph-and-alvin-bunk).

Comment: I have update my mapping to ManyToOne and OneToMany, Where ManyToOne is my Sub-agent entity, and OneToMany is my Company, I have successfully update my schema. The only problem is that I didn't perform add sub-agent. HEre's my error. 

`Expected value of type "SwipeBundle\Entity\Company" for association field "SwipeBundle\Entity\Sub_agent#$companyId", got "integer" instead` Please check my updates to my code above.

Comment: what $appStudent in the @param?

Comment: Do I still have to put getters and setters for company_id?